# Replacement for csaps() and the `p` argument in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

Has anyone come across a Python replacement for the [`csaps()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/csaps.html) in MATLAB's curve-fitting toolbox?

I am aware of Scipy's offerings in `interpolate` and `signal` but I can't find anything that implement's `csaps()`'s smoothing parameter argument, `p` (though I may have missed it).

The function and argument I'm interested in is [described here on p211](http://books.google.com/books?id=m0QDJvBI_ecC&lpg=PA142&vq=Smooth&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q=Smoothing%20parameter&f=false) in detail (and FORTRAN).

Thought I'd ask before diving in myself.

Comment: Have you tried [UnivariateSplines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline)? You can specify the degree of smoothing (3 for cubic), weights and smoothing factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation of de Boor's work in the [pywafo](https://code.google.com/p/pywafo/) project.

This is the [actual module](http://pywafo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pywafo/src/wafo/interpolate.py). It also depends on their [polynomial module](http://pywafo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pywafo/src/wafo/polynomial.py).

The code appears to be LGPL and GPL v3, so give it some citation love if you use it.